# Windows 10 and Ubuntu dual boot issues

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-10

I currently have Windows 10 Pro x64 installed (no upgrade because my PC is custom-built).

Whenever I boot into the Ubuntu 14.04.2 live USB, it doesn't give me an option to install it alongside Windows 10.

I don't have UEFI enabled and I'm not sure if the 'Something else' option will allow me to boot into Windows anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: use Disk Management to create a separate partition(I mean free unallocated space) and try to install now

Comment: Already have a separate partition with free space and yes, my disk is basic.

Comment: then install by "something else option",@JasonVS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: I would install using "Something else", but I'm afraid GRUB2 isn't going to detect Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a useful guide on how to use the "something else" function that Ravan is talking about: [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/343352/341921)

Comment: I would install using "Something else", but I'm afraid GRUB2 isn't going to detect Windows 10.